# How to include jwt secret in application.yaml for Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, token

I am trying to set up the values for the security for jwt in a java application.

Normally in application.properties you could have:

```
security.jwt.secret= "something"
security.jwt.expiration-in-ms = "here you will set the ms"
```

What is the right/proper way of setting the jwt secret and expiration in application.yaml?

Currently I have:

```
security:
jwt:
secret: "jwt-tokens-that-should-be-changed-production"
```

I saw online that this is how you write de jwt secret in yaml, but for the expiration I saw different ways of doing it like using:

```
expiration: 608500
```

or

```
expire-length: 30000
```

But now I'm not sure if it's the correct way to set the jwt secret and expiration.

Also getting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hN9d.png)

But I do have it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn9Li.png)

Comment: It really depends on your application.

Comment: What are your recommendations?

Comment: I've added more detail to the title based on your question (because "how to write application.yaml" is too vague to help folks understand what your question is about). I also formatted your code as code instead of blockquotes. Could you please include the error text in the question instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yaml indentation is important. Indentation maintains the hierarchy in the file. So in your case, it should look like:

```yaml
security:
  jwt:
    secret: "jwt-tokens-that-should-be-changed-production"
```

It's not important how many spaces you use for indentation, but you have to be consistent throughout the whole file.

Not sure what is the question about expiration.